# Calculate the sum of digits. If the number repeats itself, do not calculate it

Tags: c

My question is how do I check if a digit is repeated in an integer *without using arrays*?

For example: 123145... 1 is repeated twice. so the output should be 15 (1+2+3+4+5)

My current code is:

```
# include "stdio.h"
int main () {
  int input = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int input = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  int digit;

  printf("Please enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d" ,&input);

  while(input > 0) {
    digit = input % 10;

    if(d0 < 1) {
        sum += digit;
        d0 = 1;
    }

    input /= 10;
  }

  printf("Sum of different digits is: %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "repeated" mean? Same digit next to each other? A digit appearing more then once in the whole number?

Comment: `if(d0 < 1) {` only executes once. Inside you're setting `d0 = 1`. Also where is it declared? this code doesn't compile (duplicate declarations...)

Comment: For example: 123145... 1 is repeated twice.
so the output should be 15 (1+2+3+4+5)

Comment: Jean-François Fabre I thought about it but it's kinda long and I don't want it to be too long...

Comment: it should be a [mcve], so it has to compile.

Comment: without using arrays ? how will you check for non-subsequent duplicates then? a good way to do it is to define an array of 10 booleans and mark the values when you encounter them.

Comment: school doesn't want us to use things we didn't learn yet...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *without using arrays?* – using the bits of an `unsigned` will do just fine.

Comment: @RonSegal *school doesn't want [...]* – Bit operations like `|`, `&` and `<<`?

Comment: If you haven't learned arrays, probably you haven't learned about bit arithmetic, too. In such a case, you could define 9 variables, one for each digit, initialized with `0`; for each digit, increment the respective counter/flag only if this counter is still `0`. At the end write `d1 + 2*d2 + 3*d3 ...` Ugly, but will work.

Comment: using array is probably faster than with bit masking. Stephan idea would work too. Those assignments are sooo away from real life

Comment: Have you studied for loops?

Comment: "school doesn't want us to use things we didn't learn yet" is totally perverse (and you can quote me on that). The point of a university is to help you learn, not to restrict you from unauthorized learning. If you'd said "school doesn't want us to copy solutions we don't understand," that would be different -- but then they shouldn't be OK with you looking for a solution here.

Comment: Assignments like this are very helpful to cause people with experience to think outside the box.  It is easy to come up with a way to do it with more advanced concepts.  However, it requires a lot more thought to come up with an algorithm that does not use arrays, for loops, function calls, etc, and still keeps the code to a minimalist and understandable style.  I agree with @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but I also enjoy opening my mind to a different way of approaching a problem.

Comment: @JohnMurray: my thinking outside the box solution was to bubble sort the digits (bubble sort being convenient because it only requires comparing adjacent digits) and then do a simple scan, tossing out repeats which will then be adjacent. But it was too long to type on a cell phone. Anyway, I don't believe that's the reason for the restriction but I'd be prepared to retract if it were.

Comment: @rici LOL and Brillant.  I have seen that algorithm used to solve this type of problem.  I agree that there are many times that sorting makes a problem much simpler, but alas--we are hamstrung by cell phones. :-) . And, yes, I like the simplicity of your solution.  Our solutions are identical, except I tried to do it without a function, which means yours is easier to read.

Comment: @rici: Your out-of-the box approach uses more memory/registers and apparently much more time than the "used" map or even array (using `bool`) approach and it changes the input data which is not a good idea without need (see _const-correct coding_). In the big picture it can be good to see the larger picture, but for such simple homework stuff the established approaches are in fact better.

Comment: @too: yes, obviously. Didn't you read my answer or my rant about restricting the solution to not using arrays? Although, to be honest, the claim that modifying an `int` which is passed *by value* is not "const-correct" is highly questionable.

Comment: @rici: I just read "bubble sort" and had an array in mind, as for this task it does not make sense to use an `int` for the input, a string would be the natural approach. But as we are at it: if the input **is** an `int` there are only two possible values for each digit on a **binary** digital computer, so the sum is either 0 or `1` and the result would be as simple as `(_Bool)input` ;-).

Answer (score 5):

This is a really dumb way to solve this problem, but it uses neither arrays nor bit vectors:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool numberHasDigit(unsigned n, unsigned digit) {
  while (n) {
    if (n % 10 == digit) return true;
    n /= 10;
  }
  return false;
}
unsigned sumOfUniqueDigits(unsigned n) {
  unsigned sum = 0;
  for (unsigned digit = 1; digit <= 9; ++digit) {
    if (numberHasDigit(n, digit)) sum += digit;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

It's dumb because using an array (or bit vector) of flags is much faster, particularly for big numbers, and the code is just as simple:

```
unsigned sumOfUniqueDigits(unsigned n) {
  bool seen[10] = {false};
  unsigned sum = 0;
  while (n) {
    unsigned digit = n % 10;
    if (!seen[digit]) {
      sum += digit;
      seen[digit] = true;
    }
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Zero is a digit, and it can be repeated ... (Proof: `100`). (*later* oh wait, never mind – I am dumb too. *Any* number of zeros don't matter because they do not take part of the sum in a meaningful way. (Oops.)

Comment: I believe the OP said that he is looking for the sum of the digits, so zero would be ignoreed.  ie. sum(100) = sum(1000) = 1.  Oops.  i see that you chagned your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have avoided for loops and arrays and function calls.

Basically, we run a while loop that looks at the 9 interesting digits (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

While looking at each digit, we run another while loop to see if the current digit is in the number by using your modulus and division looping.  If the digit is in the number, then we add it to the sum.

We only look at each digit one time, so duplicates are ignored.

```c++
# include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    int sum = 0;


    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    //, now, subtract those values that do not exist in your number
    int digit = 1;  // start at 1, since 0 does not add to the sum
    while (digit < 10) {
        // check to see if the digit is in the number
        int testInput = input;

        while (testInput > 0) {
            if (testInput % 10 == digit) {
                sum += digit;
                break; // Don't test for this digit any more, so go back to the outer loop.
            }
            testInput /= 10;
        }

        digit++; // increment the digit
    }


    printf("Sum of different digits is: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A variation on the [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453194/2410359) good answer (and written as a one function call as [@John Murray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453280/2410359)) with reduced operations - on average about 2x faster.

Rather than iterate 1 to 9, it looks for a repeat of the least significant digit in the rest of the number.

```
unsigned SumUniqueDigits(unsigned n) {
  unsigned sum = 0;
  while (n) {
    unsigned lsdigit = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    unsigned mssdigits = n;
    while (mssdigits) {
      if (mssdigits % 10 == lsdigit) {
        lsdigit = 0;
        break;
      }
      mssdigits /= 10;
    }
    sum += lsdigit;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

Alternative even faster: On re-examination - failed test code.  Removed.

Comment: @rici Its right to left.   `811%8` does not occur, but `81%1` and then `8%1`.  Code tested as functional the same as yours, just a performance difference.

Comment: @rici  I had 2 mistakes in my "even faster alternative" 1) in the algorithm itself and 2) in the un-posted test code that failed to detect the error.  2nd approach removed.